# Disable index of folder/account in Thunderbird global search?

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a method of excluding certain accounts and/or folders from Thunderbird's global search index?  I have two email accounts in Thunderbird version 17.0.11 but I would like Thunderbird to index only one account not both.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer using the quick search feature (not for searching email bodies), it is much faster and avoid using the bulky index, sometimes pinned and clicking through some folders, nice feature.